# Is this legal when writing a "select" in mysql & php?

Tags: php, mysql, strcmp

I want to compare two strings as well as I want to compare the string case. My example query below:

```
mysql_query("select strcmp(strcasecmp(text,text2)) 
             from table_name 
             where option1=option2");
```

Please tell me it is correct usage of "strcasecmp" and "strcmp" or not.

Above is just a sample code. Please tell me if the usage of strcmp and strcasecmp is correct or wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: Why isn't it legal?

Comment: I don't know much please tell me. If it is okay I will proceed. Thank you for your fast reply.

Comment: Not sure what you're even trying to do with `strcmp(strcasecmp(text,text2)`. In any case, you seem to be misunderstanding the way this site works. You are expected to do your own basic research to at least *try* to answer your question *before* you ask here.

Comment: try google `strcasecmp examples`

Comment: First of all thank you for giving me such a good suggestion about this site and research. Here I just want to know if it is correct usage to get the result or not. I already checked on "google" but I found nothing about it.

Comment: I know what "strcmp" and "strcasecmp" can do but combining both can I get the exact result? I want to know it.

Comment: No, it is incorrect usage. `strcmp` and `strcasecmp` will return 0,1 or -1. Obviously, the combined usage makes no sense. Please go through [strcmp mysql reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#function_strcmp)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for you replies.

I just came to know that, strcasecmp(): This function works same as strcmp() which is case sensitive. If no case sensitivity is required, then you can use strcasecmp() function. It works as strcmp() but it does not distinguish between uppercase and lowercase letters.